# Harry Potter Fanfic where Harry is switched with an alternate version of himself as a subordinate of Grindelwald

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Looking to see if anyone remembers the name of a Harry Potter fanfic where he is switched with an alternate dimension version of himself. All I can remember is that in the alternates dimension he was a subordinate of Gellert Grindelwald and Tom Riddle was some sort of hippy.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be greatly improved if you went through the checklists here; [How to ask a good Story-ID question?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/222428/How%20to%20ask%20a%20good%20story-ID%20question?) and here; [How to ask a good (fan fiction) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fan-fiction-story-id-question)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the fan fiction you are looking for is “[The Heir of Gellert Grindelwald](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10850467/1/The-Heir-of-Gellert-Grindelwald).”

> *What if an escaped, Ex-Dark Lord stole an abandoned Boy-Who-Lived from the doorstep of his aunt's house and raised him as his own? What will happen when Albus Dumbledore comes across the adopted son of his enemy and teen love? And how will the Wizarding World fare against a Harry Potter who's been trained by a somewhat insane wizard and his adopted daughter?*